# Magento 1.7.0.2 - One Page Checkout Continue Button not Working

Tags: jquery, magento

good morning everyone. I'm having trouble solving this problem with magento. The error shown is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMethod' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):824)
```

It occurs every time i click in continue button on the onepagecheckout page and it will not let me advance to make the purchase as a gust or to register a new acc.
Can anybody help me? I've tried so much and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the admin panel.

System->Configurations->Sales->ShippingMethods

And then disable the below methods:

UPS
USPS
FedEx
DHL (Deprecated)
DHL

It should work after.